# SQL using Count and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to Select total number of customers based on State and their most recent orders which is DateFilled.

```
select CustomerLastName,CustomerFirstName, [State], DateFilled from customer


State  Total#CustByState    RecentDateFilled 
CA        100                04/01/2014
AZ        80                 04/23/2014
OR        120                02/02/2014
```

Comment: ...And?  Are you getting an error or something?

Comment: i am not able to frame the syntax to get the output. Error comes after

Comment: You are not able to what?  What is the error and what does it come after?

Comment: OK, is the second part another table, or is it the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Simple grouping will give you the Count and latest order, although of course this is the most recent order of Any customer in that state?

```
SELECT [State], COUNT(*) as TotalCusts, Max(DateFilled) as LastDateFilled
FROM Customer
GROUP By State;
```

If you need a count of distinct customers (Assuming some key elsewhere on your table):

```
SELECT [State], COUNT(DISTINCT CustId) as TotalCusts, Max(DateFilled) as LastDateFilled
FROM Customer
GROUP By State;
```

Comment: Thanks. COUNT(*) indicates count of CustomerFirst and CustomerLastName.

Comment: You possibly want just distinct customers ... Does your customer table have a Key of some sort, e.g. Surrogate ID?

Comment: I don't see a CustID referenced